# Spinner, strings can be seen in the background

Tags: android, android-spinner

I use to change the difficulty from my game a Spinner Item and use the strings "Leicht","Mittel","Schwer" then i took as background an drawable file, but when i start the application i can see in the background the strings i used for the spinner.. can i hide the strings? that i see just the drawable background?

```
schwierigkeitsgradAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"  Leicht","  Mittel","  Schwer"});
    schwierigkeitsgradAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    schwierigkeitsgrad.setAdapter(schwierigkeitsgradAdapter);
```

and the xml code:

```
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/schwierigkeitsgrad"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnschwierigkeit"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Comment: Add first item as empty "" and check

Comment: yes but when i took easy or heavy then are this strings i the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to hide spinner text during selection:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);  
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {  
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
        // hide selection text  
        ((TextView)view).setText(null);  
        // if you want you can change background here  
     }  
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }  
     });
```

To show spinner items use:

```
String[] test=new String[]{"easy", "medium", "heavy"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(yourActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   schwierigkeitsgrad.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: okay it works thank you! But where can i add now a String ? items like "easy", "medium", "heavy"

Comment: i don;t understand..you want to set text to spinner?

Comment: yes, when i click on the spinner that i have a DropDownViewResource

Comment: yes your dropdown Resource is populated using your `{"  Leicht","  Mittel","  Schwer"}` string array

Comment: But the Spinner dont show me my StringArray..can you send me the code with string array maybe?